# Why is a Javascript function without declared parameter working?

Tags: javascript, function, parameters

I'm writing a hangman game. With the help of Google I have a function to check if a letter is in the word, but I don't understand how, although I never declare the parameter "chosenLetter" of my function, this is able to give "chosenLetter" exactly the value of the specific letter I click on. Nor how "getElementById(chosenLetter)" can pick exactly the letter I click on to disable the button.
Same thing with the "guessedWord" function, where "letter" is never declared, yet it selects a letter to check for in the "guessed" array

```
let answer = '';
let maxWrong = 5;
let mistakes = 0;
let guessed = [];
let wordStatus = null;

function guessedWord() {
wordStatus = answer.split('').map(letter => (guessed.indexOf(letter) >= 0 ? letter : '_')).join('');

document.getElementById('word').innerHTML = wordStatus;}

function generateButtons() {
let buttonsHTML = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.split('').map(letter => 
    `
    <button
        class = "btn"
        id = '` + letter + `'
        onClick = "handleGuess('` + letter + `')"
    >
    ` + letter + `
    </button>
    `).join('');

    document.getElementById('alphabet').innerHTML = buttonsHTML;}

function handleGuess(chosenLetter) {
if (guessed.indexOf(chosenLetter) === -1) {
    guessed.push(chosenLetter)
} else {
    null;
} 

document.getElementById(chosenLetter).setAttribute('disabled', true);

if (answer.indexOf(chosenLetter) >= 0) {
    guessedWord();
    checkIfGameWon();
} else if (answer.indexOf(chosenLetter) === -1) {
    mistakes++;
    updateMistakes();
    checkIfGameLost();
}}
```

As I'm new at javascript, I'm generally trying to understand how is it possible that parameters not declared can seem to declare themselves so specifically? I don't know if I'm asking the wrong question, but that's the only thing in the code which I can't understand nor explain

Comment: Function arguments are declared automatically when a function is invoked. You're passing the value on this line: `onClick = "handleGuess('\` + letter + \`')"`.

Comment: Side note; you are using template literals as normal strings.  That defeats the purpose of using them, when using interpolation is much more benefical.  Example: `\`<button class="btn" id="${letter}">\``

Answer (score 0):

You need to read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) documentation first.

It says

> The map() method creates a new array populated with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

If we try to break the following statement in separate statements,

```
wordStatus = answer.split('').map(letter => (guessed.indexOf(letter) >= 0 ? letter : '_')).join('');
```

You will find,

```
let splittedAnswer = answer.split(''); // This will split the answer string and crate an array with all the characters in answer.

const callbackFunction = (letter) => {
    return guessed.indexOf(letter) >= 0 ? letter : '_';
}
let newArray = splittedAnswer.map(callbackFunction);
let joinedString = newArray.join('');
```

As you can see you are declaring a callback function. You are passing that function to the `array.map()` method. Now the array.map() method will call the function with 3 params `currentItemInTheArray, currentIndex, theSourceArray`. As you have declared only the first param in your callbackFunction i.e. currentElementInTheArray you will get the first param. You could declare your callback array like this,

```
const callbackFunction = (item, index, arr) => {
    console.log(item);
    console.log(index);
    console.log(arr);
}
```

And now if you call

```
[1,2,3].map(callbackFunction);
```

You will get the following output,

```
1 //currItem
0 //index
[1,2,3] //source array

2 //currItem
1 //index
[1,2,3] //source array

3 //currItem
2 //index
[1,2,3] //source array
```

But you are doing it inline, that is why you were not following. I hope now it is clear to you.

Comment: Okay, sounds like I've stumbled upon something more advanced than I was going for hehe so basically the way it works is that when I add .map(), what that will automatically add in the brackets, is item, index and source array. And by me adding the call back function in the item spot, my parameter letter will be declared as each item in the array? Meaning every item in answer.split?

Comment: Yes. You got it right. The map method will call your callbackFunction with each item of the source array.

Answer (score 0):

This is how functions work, you pass an argument as an input and to use that argument in your function you use parameters in the function definition which act as placeholders for your input and then you can use the parameters anywhere inside your function.

**Example**: In the function *guessedWord()*, you are using a *map* function which takes a callback function as an argument. So the work *letter* is actually the parameter of the callback function and parameters don't need declaration they are just placeholders.

Answer (score 0):

`generateButtons` is going to insert into the HTML element "alphabet" something that looks like this:

```js
    <button
        class = "btn"
        id = 'a'
        onClick = "handleGuess('a')"
    >
      a
    </button>
    <button
        class = "btn"
        id = 'b'
        onClick = "handleGuess('b')"
    >
      b
    </button>
    ...
```

Those `onClick` handlers will be function that pass the various letters as the first (and only) argument to `handleGuess`.

`handleGuess` is a function declared to take a single parameter, which is known *internally* to the function as `chosenLetter`.  But when you call it, you do not have to pass it a variable with the *name* `chosenLetter`.  Javascript doesn't care about that.  You could pass it a variable named `foobar` and it would be fine, or you could just pass it the raw value.

For a simpler example, let's say we had a simple function:

```js
function area (height, width) {
  return height * width
}
```

we could call it in various ways, including:

```
const height = 5;
const width = 8;

area (height, width) //=> 40

// or

const h = 6
const w = 7

area (h, w) //=> 42

// or

const rectangle = {
  height: 3,
  width: 10
}

area (rectangle.height, rectangle.width) //=> 30

// or simply

area (4, 9) //=> 36
```

The same principle applies to `handleGuess`

Comment: Right, I totally missed the call to the handleGuess function! Now it makes sense. Thank you!

Answer (score -3):

in JavaScript
variables that don't get declared will get automatically assigned to the global scope

is simple words it will declare it self :)

in your case something different is happening

you are passing the letter as a parameter to the function

```
onClick = "handleGuess('` + letter + `')"
```

and this is why it makes all the magic come alive :)

the same goes to the id property

```
 id = '` + letter + `'
```

passing the information about which specific letter you are pressing on make it so that the JavaScript Engine know which button is being pressed and that is how it know what letter you chose and what he need to disable

Comment: This answer simply confuses the issue.  There is nothing here about undeclared variables.  And StackOverflow has a jobs board.  Feel free to use it.  But don't use the Q  A area for job-searching activities.